# Minimum Value of Summation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i x_i = b$, where all $a_i$ and $b$ are constants, and $a_i > a_{i+1}$. Let $c = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$. For: 
(i)$x_i, a_i, b \in \mathbb{R}$ 
(ii)$x_i, a_i, b \in \mathbb{R}^+$ 
(iii)$x_i, a_i, b \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ 
Is it possible to find out the minimum value of $c$? If so, what is the minimum?

Comment: Are all $a_i,x_i\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @vrugtehagel yes. I'll add that to the question.

Answer (score 2):

In general there isn't a guarantee that there will be a minimum value (i.e. $c$ could be as close to $-\infty$ as you desire).  For example, consider the case when $a_1 = 2$ and $a_2=1$ and $b=0$.  Then the question is: minimize $2x_1 + x_2$ subject to $2x_1 + x_2 = 0$.  Take $x_2=-10000$ (for example) and then $x_1 = \frac{10000}{2}$.  Your $c$ value becomes $-5000$... and can be made as small as you like by making $x_2$ more negative.

Comment: what if I restrict $a_i$, $b$, and $x_i$ to positive real numbers?

Comment: @user108544, maybe if you say non negative instead of positive.  If you say positive you can probably have cases where you get arbitrarily close to 0.